# Sudoku as CSP (arc consistency)

Tags: algorithm, constraints, sudoku, consistency

For a study assignment I've recreated Norvig's algorithm in C# to solve sudoku's as a Constraint Satisfaction Problem (CSP) combined with local search with as heuristic the amount of possible values for a square. Now I need to create an extension or variant of it and I'm kind of confused about to what degrees the algorithm ensures arc consistency. What the current algorithm basicly does for this is:

- Initialize the possible values (domains) of each square as [1,...,n*n].
- Each assignment of a value to a square is done by eliminating each possible value from the domain and updating every peer (square in the same subgrid/row/column) by removing the assigned value from their domains. (Doesn't this fully ensure arc consistency because these are the only constraints between peers; that they may not have the same value?)
- When eliminating a value from a square's domain it also checks whether there's only 1 square left for this value in its unit. If so, it assigns it to that square (also by eliminating possible values, reducing it to just that value).

Now my question is: does this algorithm ensure complete arc consistency? And if not, how could I improve my CPS algorithm for this?

If anyone could help me out on this it'd be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprise you add local search as the Sudoku is really trivially solved in CP (usually without any branching). Anyway, Arc consistency may have three different meanings:

- Establishing arc consistency over a constraint network: roughly means you call the filtering algorithm of your constraints until reaching a fix point. This is done by all solvers by default. People using this term usually assume that each constraint has its own arc-consistency algorithm (see next point), which is quite true for binary constraints but usually wrong in the general case (and real life problems).
- Establishing arc consistency for a constraint: roughly means removing from each variable, all values that belong to no solution OF THAT CONSTRAINT (regardless the rest of the model). It depends of the filtering algorithm you use for the constraint (you can have many with different tradeoff between filtering power and runtime).
- Establishing arc consistency on a problem: imagine you model your entire problem using one custom global constraint, then apply previous definition.

So do you establish AC on the entire problem? This means do all unfiltered variable/value assignment belong to a solution? From what you describe, the answer is no.

Do you establish AC on each of your constraints? Well, this depends on your model. If you only use binary constraints to state your problem, then I would say yes. If you want to improve filtering, you should use global constraints, such as AllDifferent. The arc-consistent filtering algorithm of this constraint is more complex than what you describe, but it is also more powerful!

You can give a look at this [example](https://github.com/chocoteam/samples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/chocosolver/samples/integer/Sudoku.java) that uses the [Choco Solver](http://choco-solver.org/). 
You can also use different consistency levels (such as bound consistency).